# Change settings in the Appxmanifest for differnt solution configuration (UWP project)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, uwp

I have JavaScript hosted UWP project with package.appxmanifest.
Manifest has setting StartPage, I would like to change it based on testing/production build (they should point to the different urls).

Looks that xml transformation doesn't work for such project types.
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've got around this in projects is to create the additional build configurations for the solution using the Configuration Manager (right-click solution -> Configuration Manager) and then make a copy of the AppxManifest, manipulate the values you want for the various build configurations and give the files names that relate to them, i.e Package.Test.xml.

You'll then want to setup your Build Events for the app project (right-click project -> Properties) to copy the file during a Pre-build like this:

[image: Pre-build events]

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion helped me. Looks that vs 2015 doesn't support editing prebuild events from ui for jsproj type, so I have to edit proj file xml manually (by adding command to <PropertyGroup/><PreBuildEvent/> tag).